# Port forwarding between docker containers

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I run a nginx container `sudo docker run --name some-nginx -d -p 8030:8030 --rm -v /home/username/nginx_test/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro nginx:1.15.8alpine`

**/home/username/nginx_test/nginx.conf:**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  /dev/null;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events { 
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept on;  
    use epoll;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings and client, log settings
    ##



    server {
        listen       8030;
        set $port_endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8080;

        location / {
            proxy_pass $port_endpoint;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
    }
}
```

On http://127.0.0.1:8080, there is django project docker container.

It run by type: `sudo docker run --name some-nginx -d -p 8080:8080 --rm some/django:0.1`, and

It has **uwsgi file:**

```
[uwsgi]
chdir              = /smaple_django
wsgi-file          = /smaple_django/smaple_django/wsgi.py
master             = true
processes          = 10
http               = :8080
vacuum             = true

max-requests       = 1000
harakiri           = 10 

enable-threads     = true
lazy-apps          = true
single-interpreter = true
```

It works well individually so that my browser at http://127.0.0.1:8080(django container), it shows django front page.

But When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8030 in my browser, it shows 502 bad gateway on nginx. I think it has to be connected to http://127.0.0.1:8080 by these **nginx.conf** lines:

```
server {
        listen       8030;
        set $port_endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8080;

        location / {
            proxy_pass $port_endpoint;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
    }
```

It seems that there is some bad slip in nginx container and django container.

Where did I make a mistake? How can I solve it?

Comment: in your nginx container config you should be referring to the other container using its hostname rather than your localhost ip (127.0.0.1) which does not work.

`sudo docker run --name some-nginx -d -p 8080:8080 --rm some/django:0.1` also here you probably meant for name to be something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each container has its own loopback interface, it's own 127.0.0.1. Talking to that will talk to the container internally and not your host where you've published the port. Between containers, you communicate by placing them on the same user created docker network, and using container name, id, or alias to reference the containers. A compose file with a v2 or v3 syntax does this automatically, so I'd recommend going that direction.

```
sudo docker network create nginxnet

sudo docker run --net nginxnet --name some-nginx -d -p 8030:8030 --rm -v /home/username/nginx_test/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro nginx:1.15.8alpine

sudo docker run --net nginxnet --name some-nginx -d -p 8080:8080 --rm some/django:0.1
```

Using this config:

```
server {
        listen       8030;
        set $port_endpoint http://some-nginx:8080;

        location / {
            proxy_pass $port_endpoint;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up port forwarding between containers even after they've been started, without them being on the same Docker network. This can be achieved using network namespaces.

```
>       +-------------+                                   +--------------+  
>       |             |                                   |              |  
>       |  Container1 | --------------------------------->|  Container2  |  
>       |             | listen :2222                  :22 |              |  
>       +------+------+      docker to docker forward     +-------+------+
```

You can utilize the tool available at [iproute2-namespace-host-port-forward](https://github.com/inceabdullah/iproute2-namespace-host-port-forward) to accomplish this.

```bash
SOURCE_CONTAINER_ID=<SOURCE_CONTAINER_ID>
DEST_CONTAINER_ID=<DEST_CONTAINER_ID>

docker run --privileged \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v /proc:/proc_host \
    --network=host -dit nshostforward \
    --destination-to=docker \
    --source-container-id=$SOURCE_CONTAINER_ID \
    --source-port=2222 \
    --dest-container-id=$DEST_CONTAINER_ID \
    --dest-port=22
```